# Error: Chart cannot save an item after 10 attempts

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, microsoft-chart-controls

My miniture web application does very little: reads SQL and displays charts, based on an item code passed in the query string. It worked fine for months, today I suddenly got this error message:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Chart cannot save an item after 10 attempts.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.IOException: Chart cannot save an item after 10 attempts.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[IOException: Chart cannot save an item after 10 attempts.]
   System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler.GetChartImageUrl(MemoryStream stream, String imageExt) +532
   System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +243
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +240
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +253
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter output) +87
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +53
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +240
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +240
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +240
   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +38
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4240

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4952; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4955
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My DBA helped me solve it. A hard disk ran out of space and a TempFolder needed for the charts was full, thus preventing charts from being saved there as per above error.